# Up to how much damage can Zarya do?

Tags: overwatch

Zarya's passive is Energy, which allows Zarya to gain more damage on her Particle Cannon, the Plasma Bomb, and her Ult as she absorbs damage on her shields.

Visually, the orb on her weapon becomes larger and glows brighter. But nowhere in-game, or on the wiki does it state how the damage scales as she "stores" more damage.

Up to how much damage can Zarya dish out in addition to the base damage as she absorbs damage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Zarya](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Zarya)'s damage scales with Energy with a 1%:1 ratio. Once at 100 Energy, she deals double damage with her Particle Cannon. Her primary fire goes from 95 DPS to 190 and her alternate will deal anywhere from 45 to 90 damage.

Comment: This is assuming you can keep the beam on the enemy 100% of the time.  If the enemy is moving and you are not a robot, the damage done is significantly less: https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ieopo/zaryas_guns_primary_fire_is_broken_video_inside/

Answer (score -2):

She has a 95 base dps. 100 charge makes a 190 dps. With a nanoboost, its a 285 dps. With a Mercy, 375 dps. With a Zenyatta, 487.5 dps. Yea, she can kill almost any base character within a second...